# development of a compiler for .NET

Tags: c++, .net, compiler-construction

I'm developing a simple compiler for .Net, in C++, but am having problems with my include  system, therefore not seem to find a way to recognize what kind of method I'm calling from dll if it is void , string, int...
so, my include system call the .net dll call

```
@include System
@include System:Windows:Forms
```

when will generate the code, need to know, what kind of method...
I wonder if anyone knows a way to get the type of methods, without using tools .net

One way I thought of using it: Create an application in C# or another .net language to generate a TXT, and this txt, contain the name of the methods and their proper type, and at compile time, I carry this txt and caught at compile time the type of method

But, I want to know, if have an another way.

> ---

About this program that I talked is that:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Reflection;

ref class Reflector
{
public:
    void LoadAndReflect(String^ assemblyFileName)
    {
        Assembly^ assembly = Assembly::Load(assemblyFileName);
        array<Type^>^ types = assembly->GetTypes();
        StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter("mscorlib.txt");

        for each(Type^ t in types)
        {
            array<MethodInfo^>^ methods = t->GetMethods();

            for each(MethodInfo^ method in methods)
            {
                String^ base = method->ReturnType->ToString();
                array<String^>^ auxBase = base->Split('.');
                if(auxBase->Length > 1)
                    sw->WriteLine(String::Format("{0} <::> {1}", auxBase[1], method->Name));
                else
                    sw->WriteLine(String::Format("{0} <::> {1}", auxBase[0], method->Name));
            }
        }
        sw->Close();
    }
};

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    Reflector^ ref = gcnew Reflector();

    Console::WriteLine("Reflection on {0}", "mscorlib.dll");
    ref->LoadAndReflect("mscorlib.dll");
    return 0;
}
```

And, in compiler time, I open that txt and I get the method type

Comment: why not reflect at compile-time?

Comment: Ok, how I can do this in C or in C++ ??

Comment: Use the IMetaDataAssemblyImport interface.  The C# compiler source code is available from SSCLI20, csharp/sscomp/import.cpp